# Using MonoDroid Library apk from Java code

Tags: java, xamarin.android

If i created a apk library with monodroid. Can i u use this just in Eclispe(Java) and do my rest code in Java ?

Answer (score 0):

In short: no. A DLL compiled from a Mono for Android class library relies on the Mono runtime in order to run it, which wouldn't be present in a normal Java Android application. It is possible to go in the other direction though, and use Java libraries within a Mono for Android app. Xamarin has documentation of how their architecture available [here](http://docs.xamarin.com/android/advanced_topics/architecture).

That said, in some cases it is possible to access C# code from Java code when you're in the scope of a Mono for Android application. [This question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6814478/using-c-sharp-library-with-mono-for-android-from-java-code) has some good details about that.